# Can not refer to class packed in Jar1 that zipped in Jar2 while running Jar2

Tags: java, eclipse, executable-jar, buildpath

I'm getting this weird issue when my colleague runs my Jar in JRE of same version as my development environment (Java1.7 + Eclipse Indiago).

1. Add a Jar to build path and refer to some Classes in this jar;
2. Compile, run the project as Java application successfully in Eclipse;
3. Export the project as Runnable Jar with option - 'Package required libraries into generated Jar'.
4. Run the exported Jar in command line 'java -jar xxx.jar' in my computer and get expected result.
5. Run the same Jar in another computer with same JRE but get something error like 'ClassNotFound' telling that the class referred from inner Jar can not be found, as shown below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/test/commo
n/communication/BaseNotificationEvent
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoa
der.java:56)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.test.common.communicatio
n.BaseNotificationEvent
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 14 more
```

The solution so far is to export runnable jar with option 'copy required libraries into sub-folder next to generated Jar', and this works both in my and another computer.

But I am not take this as ultimate solution for I have to transfer multiple files rather a single Jar while releasing my program...which seems not elegant ^_^

Comment: I guess you mean Eclipse Indigo which has been released in 2011. Please enjoy [Eclipse Oxygen.3a](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/) that may not have this problem instead. Oxygen.3a requires Java 8 to run but can be used also to write Java 1.7 code.

Comment: Please get specific details for point 5 and add them to the post.  Is it a ClassNotFoundException or a NoClassDefFoundError?

Comment: I've pasted exception details, please check it, thanks a lot.

Comment: I'd start by first checking what specifically is included in your fat jar. It seems like it's missing a dependency.

Comment: The thing is I can run this jar standalone in one JRE but get exceptions while run it in another JRE with same version.